# Secure REST API from unwanted requests

Tags: rest, jwt, mean-stack

I have a MEAN stack web app and I use REST API to connect to the database.

My question is how can I protect it from unwanted http requests?

I already use token verification (JWT) before accessing the database but if the attacker has a token (all he needs is to register to the web app) then he'll be able to access it.

Thanks